# Serialize a Zipper?

Tags: serialization, clojure, zipper

```
repl> (-> root zip/down zip/right)
[{:answer-keys [5 6], :id 3} {:l [{:id 2, :answer-keys []}], :pnodes [{:answer-keys [2 3 4], :id 1}], :ppath nil, :r ({:answer-keys [7], :id 4})}]
```

I see this data when I print out the zipper on the repl. I am thinking that this may be all the data I would need to serialize a zipper? Is it possible to de-serialize a zipper from the provided data?

I am looking for something like the zip/serialize and zip/deserialize function imagined below.

```
(def s (zip/serialize (-> root zip/down zip/right))) ;; s is a string
(def d (zip/deserialize s)) ;; d is a zipper location
;;And I can go on using the deserialized zipper d without any difficulty.
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the magic of zippers is they are a data structure that represents everything needed to produce arbitrarily modified versions of tree structures. **zippers print and read just fine** because they are **proper values** and don't require any state

you can "serialize" it with `pr-str` and "deserialize" it with `read`

make a zipper:

```
user> (zip/vector-zip [[1 [2]][3][4]])
[[[1 [2]] [3] [4]] nil]
user> (def s (zip/vector-zip [[1 [2]][3][4]]))
#'user/s
user> s
[[[1 [2]] [3] [4]] nil]
```

serialize it to a string:

```
user> (def serialized-s (pr-str (zip/next s)))
#'user/serialized-s
user> serialized-s
"[[1 [2]] {:l [], :pnodes [[[1 [2]] [3] [4]]], :ppath nil, :r ([3] [4])}]"
```

read it back:

```
user> (def deserialized-s (read-string "[[1 [2]] {:l [], :pnodes [[[1 [2]] [3] [4]]], :ppath nil, :r ([3] [4])}]"))
#'user/deserialized-s
```

do something with the result:

```
user> (zip/root deserialized-s)
[[1 [2]] [3] [4]]
```

Comment: Whoa, that is very cool. And I was thinking it was creating a closure all the way back up the path. Haha. My only remaining question then is why does print-str serialize a expression, while read-string only deserializes the first item from a string? It just seems a bit odd that they don't perfectly "match".

Comment: The `print` family of functions are for human consumption, not for serialization. For example, strings and symbols print the same, so information is lost. Instead, use `pr-str`, which prints to a computer-friendly format (and is more or less the inverse of `read-string`).

Comment: @StephenCagle If you have another question that is basically unrelated to this one, I recommend you ask it as a question, instead of as a comment on one of the answers here. But in short, there is no inconsistency: `print-string` prints one value to a string, and `read-string` reads one value from a string.

Comment: @amalloy, fixed :) fortunately in this case the output it the same

Comment: just one note: As I understood zippers, they actually represent state of a subterm plus properly typed navigation operations.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Arthur's answer:

You probably also need to serialize the metadata that clojure.zip puts on its zippers, since that seems to be where it keeps track of the `branch?`/`children`/`make-node` functions. So something like

```
(defn serialize [zipper]
  (binding [*print-meta* true]
    (pr-str zipper)))

(def deserialize read-string)
```

Comment: This isn't particularly useful because all of the metadata values are functions, which are generally unreadable.